# Getting image from servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to get a photo in my jsp pages. I implemented the servlet in this way (in doGet method):

```
{...

byte[] imageData = u.getFoto();

response.setContentType("image/jpg");

response.getOutputStream().write(imageData);

..}
```

where `u` is a `User` type.

My question is: how can I set the src path in my jsp page to retrieve the image from Servlet??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would specify the mount point in your `web.xml`, with something like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/img/myservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

That will take the servlet named `MyServlet` and mount it to `/img/myservlet`. Then, in your jsp you would just use an `img` tag pointing to the `url-pattern` specified above.

```
<img src="/img/myservlet" />
```

Note: if your webapp is not mounted to /, you will also need to specify the contextPath for the application in the path.